# Сравнивание двух чисел с заданной точностью

Tags: javascript

Необходимо в функции сделать сравнивание двух чисел, с заданной точностью, но как это сделать, не понимаю:
Вот моя функция, но она, мягко говоря, не идеальна, так как я походу запутался в операндах

```
function сomparison(a, b, precision) {

  let num = (a > b ? a : b) 

  return Math.abs(num <= precision ? num : precision)
}
```

Вот еще такой вариант есть, но везде не сходится

```
   function сomparison(a, b, precision) {

  if (a - b <= precision)
    return true
  else {
    return false
   }
  }
```

Пример:

```
console.log(сomparison(1, 0.5, 0.5)) // true
console.log(сomparison(10, 9.7001, 0.3)) // true
console.log(сomparison(-1, -0.5, 0.5)) // true

console.log(сomparison(1, -2, 0.1)) // false
console.log(сomparison(-1, -0.699, 0.3)) // false
console.log(сomparison(-1, -0, 0.5)) // false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return Math.abs(x - y) <= eps
```